# C - Reads new line in a .txt

Tags: c, fopen, fgets, fread

I am making a program that reads a file and counts how many words the .txt have. The program is working just fine, the problem is that if the txt have a break line it stops reading, so i have to put all my text in one line. As far as i know the problem is in fgets, that stops reading when it reaches EOF or a new line. My question is: How do i reads my text even with new lines ? Do i have to use fread() ? If so, would i do? Below is the part of the code where i read the .txt and put in an array.

```
char linha[10000];
int grandezaStrings = 100000;
int i = 0;
int contadorString = 0;    

    //  This line reads the file.
    fgets (linha, grandezaStrings,myFile);

    // Used for special characters
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"PORTUGUESE");

    // Dynamic array to hold words
    char ** strings = (char **)malloc(grandezaStrings * sizeof (char*));
    char * pch;
    for (i=0;i<grandezaStrings; i++){
        strings[i] = (char *)malloc(100+1);
    }

    // Transfer all the words to my array.
    i = 0;
    pch = strtok(linha, " ,.!?:;()\n");
    while (pch != NULL){
        strlwr(pch);
        strings[i] = pch;
        contadorString++;
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.!?:;()\n");
        i++;
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `fgets (linha, grandezaStrings,myFile);` --> `fgets (linha, sizeof linha, myFile);` : `grandezaStrings`  does not conform to the too large.

Comment: `strings[i] = pch;` --> `strcpy(strings[i], pch);`

Comment: fgets gets one line  , you have to do while(fgets(...) != NULL ) to get all the file

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` reads up to next new line. It is *by design*. You could loop (`while (fgets(...) != NULL)`) or if you want to load everything in memory in one single read, you can just use a `fread` :

```
//  This line reads the whole file.
i = fread (linha, 1, grandezaStrings,myFile);
if (i < 0) { // test read Ok
    perror("Lettura");
    return 1;
}
linha[i] = '\0';  // add the terminating null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use fgets() to get line by line from the file and perform your operation on the line.

```
while(fgets (linha, sizeof(linha),myFile) != NULL)
{
// perform the action on the line.
}
```

Use `sizeof(linha)` as the number of characters to be read.